# Deep Copy a BindingList<Object>

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to make a clone of a `BindingList<Object>`.

I want to create a new copy of an existing list that does not share the same reference. Another complication is that my object itself contains a nested `BindingList<Object>`.

I tried the constructor method:

```
BindingList<Equation> NewEquationList = 
                         new BindingList<Equation>(OldEquations.ToList());
```

I then tried looping through the list, setting the new values:

```
BindingList<Equation> NewEquationList;
foreach (Equation OldEquation in OldEquations)
{
    Equation NewEquation = new Equation()
    {
        NewEquation.ID = OldEquation.ID,
        ...
    };
    NewEquationList.Add(NewEquation);
}
```

I tried implimenting a 'Copy Constructor' - I still don't understand how that differs from the above but it also didn't work.

I tried setting my Equation class as [Serializable] and serializing/deserializing the object however I receive an error stating that the PropertyChangedEventHandler used in my class is not marked as Serializable.

I didn't think making a value copy of a reference type would be a complicated procedure, however I am having difficulty in making this work.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

My solution was to add a Clone method into the Equation's class. I still don't understand why this worked and the 'Copy Constructor' did not.

```
public Equation Clone()
{
    Equation NewEquation = new Equation();
    NewEquation.ID = this._ID;
    ...

    //Nested BindingList:
    NewEquation.EquationVariables = new BindingList<EquationVariable>  
            (this._EquationVariables.Select(EV => EV.Clone()).ToList());

    return NewEquation;
}
```

Using the above, the following successfully created a deep copy:

```
NewEquationList = new BindingList<Equation>
        (OldEquations.Select(E => E.Clone()).ToList());
```

Comment: I don't see how your loop wouldn't work. In what way did it not work?

Comment: When I bind the new list to a new window's ListView, I can see the old list changing on the old window (both are open at the same time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do your objects (elements in the BindingList) implement ICloneable? If so then look into using [ICloneable.Clone method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then clone each object manually when creating a new list.

Your IList use i.e.

```
BindingList<Equation> NewEquationList = 
                     new BindingList<Equation>(OldEquations.ToList());
```

Just creates a copy with the same references (shallow copy).

If the objects (elements in the BindingList) are serialisable...

Have a read of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757310/c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-copy-a-bindinglist)… especially "Serialize the object then de-serialise to get a deep cloned non referenced copy".

Often the best if not the only way to deep copy collections is to do the serialise then deserialise dance.

Comment: I tried following that post before I added my question. I received an error stating that my PropertyChangedEventHandler is not marked as Serializable. I tried marking the EventHandler with `[field: NonSerialized]` but I receive an error when I try to Deserialize the object. I will look into ICloneable now.

Comment: `NewEquationList = new BindingList<Equation>(OldEquations.Select(E => E.Clone()).ToList());` - This worked perfectly! Do you know why the 'Copy Constructor' technique did not work?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm afraid not.

Comment: for me, none worked, but serialize and deserialize worked like a charm